# I am getting invalid schema error in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

> TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `P` is not a valid type at path `0`. See for a list of valid schema types.
> at Schema.interpretAsType (E:\Oil Company Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:1072:11)

and this is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose;


const productSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "please enter product name"],
        trim: true

    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "please enter product description"]

    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "please enter product price"]
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    images: [{
        public_id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        url: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }],
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "please enter product category"],

    },

    stock: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "please enter product stock"],
        default: 1
    },
    numOfReviews: [{
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        rating: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        comment: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }

    }],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.Schema("Product", productSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `mongoose.model("Product", productSchema)` instead of `mongoose.Schema("Product", productSchema)` in order to make the model you desire.